# phantomjs stuck at [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Could you tell me why the following script doesn't work? PhantomJS gets stuck at

> [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame "".

```
// phantomjs --debug=true --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --ssl-protocol=any test.js < data.json

var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var input = JSON.parse(system.stdin.read(2000));

console.log(JSON.stringify(input));

//phantom.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){ console.log(msg); }

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
        page.reason = resourceError.errorString;
        page.reason_url = resourceError.url;
};

page.open(input.address, function(status){ 

    if (status !== 'success'){
        console.log("url: "+page.reason_url+"reason: "+page.reason);
        phantom.exit(1)
    }

    page.onLoadFinished = function(){
        input.cookies = page.cookies;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
        phantom.exit();
    };

});
```

data.json

```
{"cookies": [], "address": "https://google.com"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no further instructions after the page load, it won't do anything and just sit there.

The callback of `page.open` is actually the same thing as `page.onLoadFinished`. Setting it again after it was already called won't run it a second time if there wasn't some kind of action in between (site redirect, click, form submit).

Try:

```
page.open(input.address, function(status){ 
    if (status !== 'success'){
        console.log("url: "+page.reason_url+"reason: "+page.reason);
        phantom.exit(1)
    }

    input.cookies = page.cookies;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: sorry but it still hanging. This is so weird. Sorry i've just started phantomjs yesterday

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. It works fine for me on PhantomJS 1.9.8 and 2.0.0 on Windows.

Comment: If you had an earlier version of PhantomJS, then you should register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there were errors so you know what went wrong. I suspect some kind of SSL problem.

Comment: I'm using phantomjs 1.9.0 on Linux. That was just a test to understand something about a project i'm working on. I added a phantom.exit() on my project and it worked. Thanks for your help